# How to detect that my AlertDialog is killed by system?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have my dialog based on AlertDialog.
When screen rotates (or some other config change happens), the dialog is closed by OS.

Problem is that my dialog plays audio by MediaPlayer, and when such auto-close happens, dialog is gone but sound continues to play.

Does Dialog get some chance to cleanup before it's killed by system? Or I'm forced to use Activity in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When screen rotates your Activity is destroyed and created new one.

If you have opened dialog and this dialog is not managed, it will leak. You can suppress this behaviour in manifest by defining `android:configChanges="orientation"` for `<activity>`, then instead of recreating Activity an `onConfigurationChanges` callback is called instead. There you can handle screen rotation.

If you are using `Activity.showDialog(int)` then before activity is destroyed dialog states are saved. When new Activity is created saved information is used to restore your dialogs.

---

Update

If you are looking for handling when your dialog is closed, you can use `AlertDialog.setOnDismissListener`

Comment: setOnDismissListener won't help, since it's called only if dismiss is called, which is not the case.
However, you're probably right about Dialog object being leaked if it's not stored and managed by Activity. Thanks for hint.

Answer (score 2):

Add proper permission in manifest file.

[For the activity like in this post](http://androidcodesnips.blogspot.com/2011/06/handling-orientation-change-in-android.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20Androidcodes%20%28AndroidCodes%29)

Comment: Sorry, I'm aware of those flag, but many other changes may cause your activity to restart and dialog to be killed, not only orientation change. This doesn't answer question how to detect dialog being closed by OS.

Answer (score 0):

there is onPrepareDialog, i guess there should be something like onDestroy also. Anyways, what if you handle 
onConfigurationChanged of the activity and recreate the dialog ?

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
{
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
//create dialog here again? 
}
```

update

thanks salw, you will need android:configChanges="orientation" in manifest in activity tag